# Android - pass extra information to a ListView without it being displayed, for an RSS reader?

Tags: android

I'm parsing an RSS feed using SAX

```
messages = parser.parse();
List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>(messages.size());
for (Message msg : messages){
    titles.add(msg.getTitle() + "\n" +msg.getDate() + "\n\n" + msg.getDescription());
 }
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row,titles);
this.setListAdapter(adapter);
```

This creates a nice list with the entire post included, but I'd like to just show the title and date in the list.

Here's my onListItemClick right now

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String selection = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.single);
            dialog.setTitle("Blog");
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.SinglePost);
            text.setText(selection);
            dialog.show();

    }
```

but this just pops-up whatever is in the list.

Is there a way to pass the description to the list, without it showing, so when they click the list item, the dialog just has the description?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a separate array holding only descriptions:

```
List<String> descriptions = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Message msg : messages){
    descriptions.add(msg.getDescription());
    titles.add(msg.getTitle() + "\n" +msg.getDate());
}

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String description = descriptions.get(position);
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.single);
            dialog.setTitle("Blog");
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.SinglePost);
            text.setText(description);
            dialog.show();

    }
```